# Pass parameters to flutter module from android or iOS

Tags: android, flutter

I'm experimenting with integrating a flutter module in an existing android app. Starting a view works fine using this code:

```
private fun startFlutterActivity() {
    val intent = FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine("default_engine").build(this)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

But I'm not sure on how to pass additional data e.g. an id to fetch data for to the flutter component. I know you can establish a message channel but this seems like a lot of overhead for passing stuff around.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pass the id through to the flutter engine [via the initial route](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen#initial-route-with-a-cached-engine).

So like:

```dart
    flutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(this);
    // Configure an initial route.
    flutterEngine.getNavigationChannel().setInitialRoute("showStuf?id=$id");
```

Or, in your example, you can simply add the intent extra [FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.EXTRA_INITIAL_ROUTE](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_ROUTE) to the intent.

On the flutter side you would then simply parse the initial route in your [`onGenerateRoute` handler](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html) for your `MaterialApp` or other navigator config.

Comment: Doesn't work. id you pass trough initial route won't be treated as route argument on flutter side. Instead, it will be considered as a full route url.